# Литература по углублению в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. 
Ищу книгу где можно углубленно почитать про SQL (MySQL)
Я уже пишу программку и так же у меня неплохо получается писать запросы.
Но я бы хотел углубиться, например почитать про хранимые процедуры или про тригеры и многое другое что уходит от простых sql запросов.
Ищу книгу где это можно почитать на русском языке. И пока что ничего не нашел.
прочитал Алан Бьюти - Изучаем SQL 
Кое что нашел для себя полезное но очень многое я и так знал!
Я понимаю что таких вопросов уже миллион, но по нужным не темам не нашел книг!

Comment: IMHO, хоть сто книг прочитай - без практики это всё пшик. Правильный путь: получил задачу (придумал, взял пример откуда-то, неважно). Попробовал сделать сам. Не получилось - вот тогда уже полез листать.

Comment: Дело в том что зада есть) и я ее решаю по старинке запросами и нет проблем) Просто я услышал про тригеры и хранимые процедуры и задумался о чем же я еще не знаю?

Comment: О, пошла конкретика. Вываливай задание (отдельным вопросом). А не знаешь ты до хрена и больше, я тоже. Это нормально.

Comment: для желающих ответить: лучше внесите дополнение в [описание метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info).

Answer (score 3):

Можете попробовать [Гольцман В. - MySQL 5.0. Библиотека программиста](https://www.litres.ru/viktor-golcman/mysql-5-0-biblioteka-programmista/).

Много воды, но книга достаточно неплохая. Мне много кто ее советовал не смотря на то что написана по старой версии.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вот этот ресурс посоветовал:
http://sql-ex.ru/

Регистрируешься, выполняешь интерактивные задания.

В конце можно получить сертификат.

Comment: Я видел этот сайт. Но как я понял он не расскажет мне что такое хранимые процедуры, зачем и почему